# Eloquent Update function is not updating all records

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

i want to update all user records depending on the user id , the user id is repeated more than one time and i want the update function to update all these occurrences here is my try :

```
App\Models\HistoryCostEstimation::where(['user_id'=>$user_ID])->update(['currency'=>$currenc]);
```

but this code updates only one occurrence , is there any other way to do the required purpose ?

this is the table structure
[image]

and this is a sample of the data in the table

[image]

Comment: I think you should have loop for all users.

Comment: it's not the point , the update function have to update any occurrence of the given input.
in my case let's say user id = 1 repeated 10 times then the update function have to update the 10 occurrences.
am i wrong ?

Comment: So what's the point if you haven't `foreach` loop or `fluent` ?

Comment: when you are updating 10 records having the same id , do you have to have a loop ? .. no it's just updates all these values

Comment: Why do 10 records have the same id? I think it should have different ids.

Comment: it's a table having relation with some other table called users , so when the user with id from table users loign it's stored in the table i mentioned in the question so that the id is repeated

Comment: You can use `get()` to get all the data of that user_id, then use a loop. Or you can try `sync` in eloquent, [references here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: can you update with a structure of your table

Comment: Try to update your code to be like this 
`App\Models\HistoryCostEstimation::where('user_id', $user_ID)->update(['currency'=>$currenc]);`

Comment: the same thing happens

Comment: Can you show the generated query?

Comment: Hi, did you use many-to-many relationships?

Answer (score 3):

**Solution:**

```
$user_id = 1;
$records = App\HistoryCostEstimation::where('user_id', $user_id)
                                        ->update(['cost_name' => 'New value']);
```

> Note: The eloquent where clause takes string parameters not an
>   array, also make sure your $fillable fields are set. That should do
>   the trick.

Answer (score 0):

well i found where the mistake is , the problem was that i'm taking the query inputs from a web service.

imagine the scenario that the mobile app sends me id and based on this id i did the query above in the question and i didn't but in mind that all the results are taken during the run time not before it the code was like

```
$HistoryCostEstimationID = $request->input('historyCostEstimationID');

  $type = $request->input('type');
  $newValue = $request->input('newValue');  
  $currenc = $request->input('currency');

  $user_ID = App\Models\HistoryCostEstimation::select('user_id')->where('id',$HistoryCostEstimationID)->get();
  App\Models\HistoryCostEstimation::where('user_id', $user_ID)->update(['currency'=>$currenc]);
  App\Models\HistoryCostEstimation::where(['id' => $HistoryCostEstimationID])->update([ $type => $newValue , 'currency' => $currenc]);
```

but it has to be something like

```
$HistoryCostEstimationID = $request->input('historyCostEstimationID');

  $type = $request->input('type');
  $uID = $request->input('u_id');
  $newValue = $request->input('newValue');  
  $currenc = $request->input('currency');

  App\Models\HistoryCostEstimation::where('user_id', $uID)->update(['currency'=>$currenc]);
  App\Models\HistoryCostEstimation::where(['id' => $HistoryCostEstimationID])->update([ $type => $newValue , 'currency' => $currenc]);
```

i mean i had to take the u_id before executing the query because if it is not , it will always give null